# How can I call a function automatically without using the case statement like I did in my code?

Tags: c

```
int main(void) {
    int distance = 0;
    uint8_t key;

    init_uart();

    sei();
    printf("Echo");
    while (1 == 1) {
        key = getchar();
        switch (key) {
          case 13:
            printf("\n");
            break;
          case 't':
            Trigger();
            while (MIP == 1) { };
            distance = (((ECHOHigh * pow(2, 16)) + ECHOLow) / 2000000) *(34300 / 2);
            printf("Echo is %d %d %d\n\n", ECHOHigh, ECHOLow, distance);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

I want to sample data from an echolocator and I have to press `t` to call the trigger function is there a way to call it without pressing any key and let it sample data at a constant rate?

Comment: use timer(good) or delay(bad)

Comment: Hi @user13046870, you could format your code to make it easier to read for people who want to help. Using punctuation in your question would be good, too. Furthermore, providing a snippet of your code is good, but it should be minimal and it should compile. A headline telling mentioning the word "sleep" or "delay" would also be helpful. Apart from that, what's the platform that you use?

Comment: `while (MIP == 1){};` is an infinite loop if `MIP==1`

Comment: regarding; `(ECHOHigh * pow(2, 16))`  This would be MUCH better written as: `(ECHOHigh <<= 16)`

Comment: Please post a [mcve] so we can reproduce the problem and help you debug it